# Choosing a Group for Graph Isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am trying to figure out how Luks' graph isomorphism algorithm works, I understand the clear answer given [by Misha Lavrov about trivalent graph isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3702667/850314), it basically says:

1. Construct graph $Z$ by joining graphs $X, Y$ in a specific way,
2. Find the automorphism group of $Z$,
3. If there is isomorphism between graph $X$ and graph $Y$, then, there will be an automorphism, say $\pi$, that sends vertices from $X$ to $Y$, in that case $\pi$ is the isomorphism, i.e. $X^{\pi}=Y$. If there is no such $\pi$, then graphs are not isomorphic.

But I got confused when I read [the thesis of Paolo Codenotti (page 33 to 35)](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elaci/students/codenotti.pdf), In the subsection 2.5.2 "Divide and conquer", the author describes the process of  $\rm ISO(G; X, Y )$ where $G \leq \rm Sym (X)$.

But I don't understand how $G$ is chosen, there is no clear description on the document. Say,
$\rm ISO(G; X, Y ) = \emptyset$ does that mean there is no isomorphism between $X, Y$?

That can't be because, it could be the case that there exists $H$ such that $G < H \leq \rm Sym (X)$ and $\rm ISO(H; X, Y ) \neq \emptyset$, right?

The question is, how we choose a group $G$ and be sure that if $\rm ISO(G; X, Y ) = \emptyset$ then there is no isomorphism between $X, Y$?